# How to design resource with search method on various fields?

Tags: api, rest, search, get, api-design

I'm in the process of designing a REST API for a dictionary-like service. Our goal is to support multiple language, but I will take the example of Chinese (iso code: `cmn`).

I consider my dictionaries to be resources, so for instance I get:

- http://site.io/api/cmn ← Chinese
- http://site.io/api/jpn ← Japanese

For each language I want to allow fuzzy search in the following field :

- `ort`: main orthography (*e.g.* Simplified Chinese) ;
- `ortx1`: first extra orthography (*e.g.* Traditional Chinese) ;
- `pho`: phonetic transcription (*e.g.* Hanyu Pinyin) ;
- `def`: French translation.

### Current status

Currently my API is like this:

```
/api/
    ├── dicts/
    │   ├── cmn/
    │   │   ├── any/{text}
    │   │   ├── ort/{text}   # Simplified
    │   │   ├── ortx1/{text} # Traditional
    │   │   ├── pho/{text}   # Pinyin
    │   │   ├── def/{text}
    │   ├── jpn/
    │   │   ├── any/{text}
    │   │   ├── ort/{text}   # Kanji
    │   │   ├── ortx1/{text} # Hirgana/Katakana
    │   │   ├── pho/{text}   # romaji
    └───└───└── def/{text}
```

Should I keep my current api layout or switch to another one ?

1. `…/cmn/{field}/{text}` current ;
2. `…/cmn/{text}/{field}`  ;
3. `…/cmn/{text}?{field}` use *query string* parameter to modulate my searches.
4. `…/search/{lang}/{field}/{text}` consider search as resource ;

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to use query parameters? GET /api/dicts/cmn?ort={text}&pho={text}

Comment: I would also consider a design that didn't tie you to the French translation, lest you become a victim of your own success.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the field parameter (ort, ortx1, etc) does not actually qualify as an independent resource. Also, if you see, these fields are common and repeat under each cmn subtree.

A more intuitive approach seems the 3rd one, since the field is merely a restriction in your search. This also allows for a more easier way to allow a default search mode, which would be counter-intuitive and ambiguous to allow if you used field as a resource.

The 2nd approach also faces the issue of allowing for a default search mode and field is clearly not a sub-resource for text.

The 4th approach that you mention looks reasonable if you remove `{field}` as a resource and add it as a query parameter instead.